# red_black_tree remove confusion

Tags: red-black-tree

I'm learning red black tree in wikipedia. confused about remove case 2[red_black_tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree),why is hade to rotate

Case 2: S is red. In this case we reverse the colors of P and S, and then rotate left at P, turning S into N's grandparent. Note that P has to be black as it had a red child. The resulting subtree has a path short one black node so we are not done. Now N has a black sibling and a red parent, so we can proceed to step 4, 5, or 6. (Its new sibling is black because it was once the child of the red S.) In later cases, we will relabel N's new sibling as S.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following tree:
              7b
      4r          8b
  2b      5b
1r  3r      6r

and you are removing '8', the rotation at stage 2 ensures that a black node remains at the parent of the node being removed but also ensures that parent has two children after the re-balance is complete.

after stage 2 rotation and color exchange:

```
  4b
```

2b      7r
1r  3r  5b    8b
          6r

At this point the color of 7 is saved after which a rotation is performed at 5 because its far nephew is black - in this case null:

```
  4b
```

2b      7r
1r  3r    6r    8b
        5b

After which 7 is recolored black, 6 is given the saved parent color and a second rotation at 7 is performed 
      4b
  2b      6r
1r  3r    5b  7b
                8b

At which point the 8 can be removed from the tree:
      4b
  2b      6r
1r  3r    5b  7b